# HAML iterate over collection - how to wrap groups of child elements in unique parents?

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I have an ActiveRecord collection which consists of a number of elements that each have a different `type`, (simplified names/variables) for example (if it were converted to a serializable_hash):

```
[
  {"id" => 1, "type" => "book", "title" => "title one"},
  {"id" => 2, "type" => "book", "title" => "title two"},
  {"id" => 3, "type" => "book", "title" => "title three"},
  {"id" => 4, "type" => "movie", "title" => "title four"},
  {"id" => 5, "type" => "movie", "title" => "title five"},
  {"id" => 6, "type" => "movie", "title" => "title six"}
]
```

Which I would like to output the following:

```
<h2>Book</h2>
<ul class="list-book">
  <li>title one</li>
  <li>title one</li>
  <li>title one</li>
</ul> 

<h2>Movie</h2>
<ul class="list-movie">
  <li>title three</li>
  <li>title four</li>
  <li>title five</li>
</ul>
```

I'm a bit confused about how I could go about achieving this output with HAML? So far I have begun something along the lines of:

```
- current_type = ""

- foo.each do |bar|
  - if current_type != bar.type
    %h2= bar.type
```

Then my confusion sets in when I try to think about how I could wrap each group of items in their own `<ul>` parent.

I've found myself being rather stumped on logic within HAML templates due to its nesting syntax, which leads me to believe that it truly is not the right place to carry out this logic, so perhaps if what I'm hoping for is impossible in HAML, is there a Ruby method to extract the unique `type` from the hash as an array and iterate over the collection by `type` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to think in terms of organising your data *before* writing it out to HTML. In this case you could use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) on the collection first, then iterate over each array in turn, something like:

```
- foo.group_by {|m| m['type']}.each do |type, array|
  %h2= type.capitalize
  %ul{:class => "list-#{type}"}
    -array.each do |m|
      %li= m['title']
```

(Here I’ve just used `capitalize` to create the headers, you might need something more complex depending on what you want.)

Comment: Wonderful and elegant answer, thank you. Does exactly what I was hoping for.